# ¿Cómo limpiar los datos de mi grafico barchart MPAndroidChart?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, mpandroidchart

tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

Estoy consumiendo un `servicio rest` que consulta datos con `retrofit` y los muestro en un gráfico usando `MPAndroidChart`, el problema es que cada consulta que realizo se queda la información anterior almacenada en el gráfico.

Y lo que deseo es que no suceda eso y solo muestre la información que se consulta.

Mi código

```
private void ConsultarxMeses(String fecha1,String fecha2){

        Call<List<ListaGrafico>> call = dashboardRest.ConsultarxMeses(fecha1,fecha2);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<ListaGrafico>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<ListaGrafico>> call, Response<List<ListaGrafico>> response) {
                if(!response.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                List<ListaGrafico> dataGrafico = response.body();
                CreateGrafico(dataGrafico);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<ListaGrafico>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Método de crear Gráfico

```
private void CreateGrafico(List<ListaGrafico> t){

        ArrayList<String> labelsname= new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<BarEntry> barEntries= new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> colores= new ArrayList<>();
        Description description = new Description();
        description.setText("Gráfico Estadístico");

        barChart.setDescription(description);

        BarEntry barDescarga = new BarEntry(0,t.get(0).getDescarga());
        barEntries.add(barDescarga);
        BarEntry barRetiro = new BarEntry(1,t.get(0).getRetiro());
        barEntries.add(barRetiro);
        BarEntry barExportacion = new BarEntry(2,t.get(0).getExportacion());
        barEntries.add(barExportacion);
        BarEntry barEmbarque = new BarEntry(3,t.get(0).getEmbarque());
        barEntries.add(barEmbarque);

        String[] nombresOperacion = {"Descarga","Retiro","Exportación","Embarque"};

        for(int i=0; nombresOperacion.length>i;i++ ){
            //barEntries.add(new BarEntry(i,contador));
            String tipo = nombresOperacion[i];
            labelsname.add(tipo);

        }

        BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(barEntries,"Cantidad de Descuentos por Tipo");
        barDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

        BarData barData= new BarData(barDataSet);
        barChart.setData(barData);

        XAxis xaxis= barChart.getXAxis();
        xaxis.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(labelsname));

        xaxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.TOP);
        xaxis.setDrawAxisLine(false);
        xaxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
        xaxis.setGranularity(1f);
        xaxis.setLabelCount(labelsname.size());
        xaxis.setLabelRotationAngle(270);
        barChart.animateY(2000);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segun la documentación,

> Después de llamar a invalidate(), el gráfico se actualiza y se dibujan los datos proporcionados.

Entonces al final de tu método deberias llamas al método `invalidate()`

```
private void CreateGrafico(List<ListaGrafico> t){
    ......
    ......
    // Todo el código que tienes para configurar tu chart
    xaxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    xaxis.setGranularity(1f);
    xaxis.setLabelCount(labelsname.size());
    xaxis.setLabelRotationAngle(270);
    barChart.animateY(2000);

    // luego en la última linea, llamamos a invalidate
    barChart.invalidate()
}
```

Referencia -> [MPAndroidChart](https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation/setting-data/)

Comment: Funciono, gracias.